# Reuse the same (random) value in multiple Inno Setup scripted constant occurrences

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am creating random numbers and using them in multiple places in other code section. If I use `/Create /F /SC DAILY /ST {code:MyRand}:{code:MyRand} ..."`, directly in `Code` section it generates the random each time, when it gets called. But I want it create only one random number per installation. So how can I pass the result of `MyRand` to a variable and use that variable in the other code section?

```pascal
[Code]
function MyRand(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Random(1000));
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the random number on installer start and refer to the generated value in the scripted constant function.

```pascal
var
  MyRandValue: Integer;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MyRandValue := Random(1000);
  Result := True;
end;

function MyRand(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(MyRandValue);
end;
```